# Laravel : Passing data to sessions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i am passing data to sessions like this :

```
return redirect()
       ->back()
       ->with('message', 'Incorrect email or password.')
       ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
```

And showing that `message` like this :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger {{ (Session::has('message') && Session::get('form', 'login') == 'login') ? '' : 'display-hide' }}">
    <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
    <span >
        {!! Session::has('message') ? Session::get('message') : 'Please correct your fields.' !!}
    </span>
</div>
```

The problem is that the message is not showing there. 
I have checked a lot but nothing is working.
Am i forgetting something ?

I am using ubuntu and the permissions are :

```
drwxrwxrwx 10 programmer programmer   4096 May 24 23:56 app
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer   1646 Apr 27 18:01 artisan
drwxrwxrwx  3 programmer programmer   4096 Apr 27 18:01 bootstrap
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer   1351 May 25 00:20 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer 124821 May 25 00:20 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx  2 programmer programmer   4096 May 24 23:56 config
drwxrwxrwx  5 programmer programmer   4096 May 24 23:56 database
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer    503 Apr 27 18:01 gulpfile.js
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer    212 Apr 27 18:01 package.json
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer   1026 Apr 27 18:01 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxrwx  6 programmer programmer   4096 May 24 23:57 public
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer   1918 Apr 27 18:01 readme.md
drwxrwxrwx  5 programmer programmer   4096 Apr 27 18:01 resources
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer    567 Apr 27 18:01 server.php
drwxrwxrwx  5 programmer programmer   4096 Apr 27 18:01 storage
drwxrwxrwx  2 programmer programmer   4096 Apr 27 18:01 tests
drwxrwxrwx 31 programmer programmer   4096 May 25 00:20 vendor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
return redirect()
       ->back()
       ->with('error', 'Incorrect email or password.')
       ->withInput();
```

With:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger {{ Session::has('error') ?: 'display-hide' }}">
    <button class="close" data-close="alert">x</button>
    <span >
        {!! Session::has('error') ? Session::get('error') : 'Please correct your fields.' !!}
    </span>
</div>
```

And I assume you have the CSS

```
.display-hide { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

with your code you're not using session. try that
in your controller set the data to set via Session like this

```
Session::set('data', $value);
```

and in your other page or logic just

```
$data = \Session::get("data");
```

in your case you want inputs values thinks to somthing like :

```
\Session::set(\Request::all());
```